# iOS 11 public beta 9 : UITextField textcolor can't be changed when no keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios11, xcode8

I am developing an app which required to change text colour of UITextfield.
I wrote following code for it.

```
-(IBAction)changedSegment:(UISegmentedControl *)segment{
    UIColor *color = arrColors[segment.selectedSegmentIndex];
    txtDemo.textColor = color;    
}
```

It is working fine in iOS 10. But in iOS 11 beta 9, when keyboard is hidden (resigned from responder), text color can't be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
[txtDemo setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: I tried it my friend. But didn't work. So, for solution, I call becomeFirstResponder() before color change. then resignFromResponder() after it.

Comment: This workaround did the trick for me:  txtDemo.text = txtDemo.text.

Comment: @lifjoy thanks for the workaround it helped, but do you know why this happens?

Comment: @AgentChocks: I assume it is an Apple bug or their attempt at a performance optimization.

Comment: I also discovered this problem, tried Arek's suggestion (didn't work) and then @lifjoy's suggestion, which did work.